# What does Googleway's rank by location option do?

Tags: r, google-maps-api-3, google-places-api, googleway

Looking at the documentation [here](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/googleway/versions/2.7.0/topics/google_places) for Googleway's google_places function, I see that there is an option to set the rankby parameter to "location". However this isn't an option in the actual Google Places API, and when I tried using it I got no results. Does anyone know what this does and why it isn't described in the documentation?

Comment: I've updated [`googleway`'s documentation](https://github.com/SymbolixAU/googleway/commit/0e00d8d5a3a164985f0c13bed1ae7b19cc3c9d3f) to reflect the latest Google API docs.

Answer (score 1):

Location is one of the required parameters but not in `rankby`. There is a possibility that the documentation that you are looking at is referring to an older version of Places API or it is just a typo. With the current version, you will only be able to use `prominence` and `distance` for `rankby`.

> rankby — Specifies the order in which results are listed. Note that rankby must not be included if radius (described under Required parameters above) is specified. Possible values are:
>
> - `prominence` (default). This option sorts results based on their importance. Ranking will favor prominent places within the specified area. Prominence can be affected by a place's ranking in Google's index, global popularity, and other factors.
> - `distance`. This option biases search results in ascending order by their distance from the specified `location`. When `distance` is specified, one or more of `keyword`, `name`, or `type` is required.

The correct documentation to look at is [Place Search
Documentation](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search#PlaceSearchRequests). Please always use the official documentation provided for the API. This will let you stay up to date.